# Pac4J having problems with encyption using self-signed certificate

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, x509certificate, pac4j

I'm running a Spring Boot 3.2.1 with an embedded Keycloak server

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakartaee-pac4j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pac4j-oidc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Everything works fine with no encryption and PAC4J is able to handle things nicely.
When I introduce SSL using a SSL Bundle, the web application works fine (HTTPS) and interaction with the embedded Keycloak server also works fine including this call:
https://localhost:8888/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration
when made from a web browser on the same machine.
However, when going through the authentication process Pac4J appears to throw the following error:

```
org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Error getting URL resource
    at org.pac4j.core.resource.SpringResourceHelper.getResourceInputStream(SpringResourceHelper.java:74)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.metadata.OidcOpMetadataResolver.retrieveMetadata(OidcOpMetadataResolver.java:89)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.metadata.OidcOpMetadataResolver.internalLoad(OidcOpMetadataResolver.java:76)
    at org.pac4j.core.resource.SpringResourceLoader.load(SpringResourceLoader.java:50)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration.findPkceMethod(OidcConfiguration.java:285)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.redirect.OidcRedirectionActionBuilder.addStateAndNonceParameters(OidcRedirectionActionBuilder.java:115)
    at org.pac4j.oidc.redirect.OidcRedirectionActionBuilder.getRedirectionAction(OidcRedirectionActionBuilder.java:58)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getRedirectionAction(IndirectClient.java:136)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.redirectToIdentityProvider(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:240)
    at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:160)
    at com.ebremer.server.MyCustomSecurityFilter.internalFilter(MyCustomSecurityFilter.java:79)
```

I added a trustAllCertificates and TrustAllHostnames at the system startup, but still to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a truststore with the self-signed certificate and assign it to the JVM: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/csec_ssl_jsp_start_server.html

Comment: The above is absolutely true (which I had done already), but in reviewing all of my settings, I discovered I had forgotten to update my own setting

( :AuthServer http://localhost:8888; )

that needed to be changed from http to https.

  Thank you for your response and for the excellent library!